# Russian/Cyrillic italic font

Tags: падежи, обучение, алфавит, typography

Could anyone please tell me, where I can find and download a font type of Russian italics? I haven't find any on the net so far, but I have to admit to only have looked on English and German language pages. However, since there are so many people in this world whose native language is written in cyrillic letters, I really have a hard time believing that there doesn't exist at least one.

I am not looking for anything fancy (like a special historical handwriting type of e.g. the 17th or 18th century), just normal standard type would do.

Comment: [This link](https://www.google.fi/search?q=русские+шрифты) should help you a lot. Take a look at the very first result

Comment: All the Unicode standard Windows fonts have Russian italics, Arial, Times New Roman, Verdana - all of them.

Comment: Thank you, Yellow Sky, for your reply. I wasn't aware that the Windows standard ("Regular") also includes the italic ("cursive") form. It appears logically, so I believe I should have tried before posting here.

However, would you happen to know if it is possible to download old handwriting fonts, like 'kursivniy shrift' ("cursive type") or 'rukopisniy shrift' ("hand-written type")?

Thank you again for helping me out here...

Greetings, Sascha

Comment: [Here](http://365psd.ru/all-fonts/cirillic/handwritten), to download a font, press the "Скачать" button.

Comment: @SaschaMauel Ah, if you are looking for fonts that imitate handwriting, try http://www.fonts-online.ru/font/Katherine or this one: http://www.fonts-online.ru/font/Denistina

Comment: By the way, there is some confusion between “italic” and “cursive”. IMHO the question about fonts is a bit off-topical here and might go to http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fonts

Answer (score 3):

Pretty much any more or less professional fontface for typing **texts** (not just fancy headers) supplies **жирный**, *курсив* and ***жирный курсив***. So choose just any respectable serif font such as Cambria, Times New Roman or the like (Gothic fontfaces usually have only oblique option since it is against their nature to have a italic design)

If you mean handwriting, try [this](http://www.fonts-online.ru/font/Katherine) and [this one, too](http://www.fonts-online.ru/font/Denistina). On Windows, starting with Vista, you can also use Segoe Script since it has a pretty decent handwriting font. Not *exactly* like the handwriting taught in school but a good stylization, and looks similar to what you can really see people write. The school-taught version looks [like that](http://www.paratype.ru/pstore/fsample.asp?scode=PT_PRO65) but few people actually follow it exactly after elementary school.

Answer (score 1):

You can find Cyrillic script fonts on [google fonts](https://www.google.com/fonts#), just choose it from menu on the left and manipulate with "slant"

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Italic is usually an attribute of a font like "Bold" and "Underlined". So you do not have to install any new fonts, all Russian fonts already include an Italic variety. The same is in Linux, AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://allfont.ru/cyrillic/) are good Latin+Cyrillic fonts